# React router identifier rerender

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-router, babeljs

I use a structure like this:

```
<Switch>
  <Route
         exact
         path="/log-out"
         component={ requireLogin(Logout) } />
  <Route
         exact
         path="/sign-in"
         component={ requireNotLogin(LoginPage) } />
  <Route
         exact
         path="/sign-up"
         component={ requireNotLogin(SignupPage) } />
  <Route
         path="/:user"
         component={ UserPage } />
  <Route
         exact
         component={ NotFoundPage } />
</Switch>
```

But user identifier not rendered multiple times

```
class UserPage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      isLoading: true,
      user: false
    }
    this.getUserPage = this.getUserPage.bind(this)
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.getUserPage()
  }
  getUserPage() {
    this.props.getUserPage(this.props.match.params.user).then((res) => {
      this.setState({
        isLoading: false,
        user: res.data.user
      })
    }, (err) => {
      this.setState({
        isLoading: false,
        user: false
      })
    })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div onMouseOver={ this.getUserPage }>
        { this.state.isLoading ?
          <div class="progress">
            <div class="indeterminate"></div>
          </div> : this.state.user ? <div></div> : <div>
                                                     User not found
                                                   </div> }
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

i tried componentDidUpdate(),etc. but some get infinite loop or it is being rendered once
this.props.getUserPage():

```
import axios from 'axios'

export function getUserPage(identifier) {
  return dispatch => {
    return axios.get('/Q/userPage/' + identifier)
  }
}
```

Eg when I go to /burakshen address with my link at /shenburak, it is not re-rendered

Answer (score 0):

i produced a solution like this

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.getUserPage()
  }
  componentWillReceiveProps() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.getUserPage()
    }, 1)
  }
```

componentDidMount() render on page open
componentWillReceiveProps() rerender but it does not work without setTimeout

Is there a better way?